# Extract a specific text pattern from a string

Tags: c++, string, scanf

I have a string as follows,

"0/41/9/71.94 PC:0x82cc (add)"

The desired output is the text between the brackets ( )

Ex: output = add,

for the string specified above

How is this done using sscanf?
Is there a better way to do it in C++?

Comment: describe a generic method that not only works on this one specific example, but all the possible inputs - and I'm not talking about code. just an english description.

Comment: So what exactly is this "specific text pattern"?

Comment: @Columbo the string I mentioned is the text and the pattern is the text between ( )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `string` operations exclusively:

```
std::string text = "0/41/9/71.94 PC:0x82cc (add)";

auto pos = text.find('(') + 1;
auto opcode = text.substr(pos, text.find(')', pos) - pos);
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/uKtZGU).

With `sscanf` it would look something like this:

```
std::string opcode(5, '\0'); // Some suitable maximum size

sscanf(text.c_str(), "%*[^(](%[^)]", &opcode[0]);
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/uZuuYR).

Comment: This is okay. But an answer with sscanf would be better due to my simulator restrictions

Comment: @Insanelycurious Added a `sscanf` solution.

Answer (score 0):

Its very easy, u should try yourself, think how to search in an array, then think if i could compare the content of an array or not, then every thing would be possible, as a programmer u have to create ideas, however if i were asked to write a program like this i would do that as follows:

```
int i=0, p=0;
char string="0/41/9/71.94 PC:0x82cc (add)", nstr[100];
while(string[i]!='\0')
{
while(string[i]!='(')
i++;
if (string[i]=='(')
{
i++;
goto end;
}
end:
while (string[i]!=')' || string[i]!='\0')
{
nstr[p]=string[i];
p++;
i++;
}
nstr[p]='\0';
cout<<Output = "<<nstr<<"\n";
```

I know this is very long, but this will give you deeper understanding of parsing or spliting a string, hope i help u, thank u...

Comment: I am aware of the general method, but I have code size limitations in the simulator, so was looking for specific methods.

Comment: Ok bro, but i dont have any much smaller code than this, sorry bro, best of luck...